# Upgrading to Rails4 and I cant pass this devise test that passed in Rails3

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

**undefined local variable or method `login_user'**

Why are my controllers not getting the extended `ControllerMacros` ???

Commit in question: https://github.com/shadowbq/cartoque/commit/2fba99c6eac5f9f2f0da2dd464f475cae0bae520

```
 <snip>
 Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
 <...snip>

 <snip>
   # include devise helpers in controller specs
     config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
     config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
 <...snip>

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:675:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `login_user' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::BackupExclusionsController:Class (NameError)
    from /home/shadowbq/sandbox/cartoque/spec/controllers/backup_exlusions_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'

<snip>
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
<...snip>
```

Here is full backtrace as well..

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:675:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `login_user' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::BackupExclusionsController:Class (NameError)
    from /home/shadowbq/sandbox/cartoque/spec/controllers/backup_exlusions_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `module_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:385:in `subclass'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:255:in `block in define_example_group_method'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:43:in `block in expose_example_group_alias'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in expose_example_group_alias_globally'
    from /home/shadowbq/sandbox/cartoque/spec/controllers/backup_exlusions_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

More file snippets

```
root@ubuntu:/home/shadowbq/sandbox/cartoque# head -15 spec/controllers/backup_exlusions_controller_spec.rb 
require 'spec_helper'

describe BackupExclusionsController do

  login_user

  before do
    @backup_exclusion = BackupExclusion.create
  end

  it "gets index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:backup_exclusions)
  end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rspec-rails 3, specs no longer have their type set automatically based on path, so your controller specs no longer have type `:controller`. You can either:

- reneebable this with the `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` option
- explicitly tag your controller specs with `type: :controller`